# What are the duties of WSServletContenxtListener and WSServlet

Tags: java, web-services, servlets, jax-ws

I am studding Web Services written in java. When I go through some articles in the internet I found the above two classes has been used for developing a SOAP Web Service. The article mentioned as

WSServletContenxtListener:

The listener class(com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener) mentioned above is the web service context listener, which initializes the web service context when the application context is initialized and creates a web service delegate which is used to delegate all future web service requests and route them to appropriate end point implementation defined in the sun-jaxws.xml mentioned below. This stores the created delegate in the container servlet context, so that the delegate can be accessed by other servlets.

WSServlet:

The servlet definition and it’s mapping is used to intercept the url-pattern that should be considered as web service request.

The class(com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet) acts as a dispatching servlet that routes the request to appropriate implementation class through the delegate received from the servlet context created by the listener as stated above.

But I have a little confusion about the different tasks done by these two classes. **According to my knowledge I guess that WSServlet is used to intercept all the incoming requests to the web service but I am having the doubt about the duty of WSServletContenxtListener**

Please anybody help me to clarify this clearly...

Comment: Do you know what a `ServletContextListener` is used for?

Comment: Yes... it gives notifications on ServletContext initialization and destruction

Comment: Okay, so what was your question? If you want to know what it does **exactly**, look at the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.xml.ws/jaxws-rt/2.1.4/com/sun/xml/ws/transport/http/servlet/WSServletContextListener.java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSServletContenxtListener  is a class for receiving notification events about web service context listener.

if you take a look at the class documentaion [here](https://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/jax-ws-20-fcs/arch/com/sun/xml/ws/transport/http/servlet/WSServletContextListener.html) , you can see the following methods that gets called when a something triggers a notification event about the web service  :

```
attributeAdded, attributeRemoved , attributeReplaced , contextDestroyed , contextInitialized , createContainer , createDelegate .
```

Hope that Helps .

Answer (score 0):

BTW: From Servlet 3.0 API, web.xml is no longer necessary. Metro already supports dynamic servlet registration. In non-Java EE mode (with sun-jaxws.xml), it will automatically create register the default JAX-WS Servlet. See
http://ics.upjs.sk/~novotnyr/blog/2068/deploying-jax-ws-services-on-java-7-and-tomcat-7